# Laravel 5 でのPOSTでのルーティングがうまくいかない

Tags: php, http, laravel

api/app/Http/routes.php

```
Route::resource('ranking', 'RankingController');
```

api/app/Http/Controllers/RankingController.php

```
class RankingController extends Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        return 'GET success';
    }

    public function store()
    {
        return 'POST success';
    }
}
```

上記設定でリクエスト時のパスが/rankingのときにGETだった場合はindexを、POSTだったときはstoreを呼び出すようになっているかと思います。

GETでリクエストした時は 200 okが帰ってくるのですが、POSTした時に500 internal server errorが帰ってきています。

これに関してサーバー側の問題か？laravelの設定の問題か？もわかっていません。。。
ご助言お願い致します。

【追記】
REST Client　POST送信画像
[image: REST Client POST送信画像]

Comment: csrf_token関係がうまく行っていないかもしれないです。

Comment: wwwサーバーに関しては`php artisan serve`コマンドでビルトインサーバーを建てて実行しています。

ログなどに関してはなにかはいてた記憶があるのですが今すぐに確認できない状態のため夜または明日には確認します。

`APP_DEBUG=true`設定されていました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`storage/logs/laravel-yyyy-mm-dd.log`ログファイルに以下のエラーが出ているようでしたら、  
csrf_tokenが設定されていないことによるエラーです。

```
[2015-06-01 06:50:23] local.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in /Users/who/projects/hoge_project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:46
```

csrf_tokenのチェックをOFFにするには`app/Http/Karnel.php`内の'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken'の行を削除するか、コメントにします。但し、この場合、アプリ全体でcsrf_tokenのチェックがOFFになってしまいます。

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel {
    protected $middleware = [
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
        'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
        'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
//      'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
    ];
```

特定のルートのみcsrf_tokenのチェックをOFFにしたい場合は、以下のサイトを参考にしてください。

参考サイト
http://qiita.com/rana_kualu/items/3f9d0d6b9a363fd2108e
http://qiita.com/zaburo/items/c054b47ed0a7be465bcf

もうすぐリリースされる、ver 5.1 では`app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`内で、`$except`を設定することで、特定のルートのみcsrf_tokenのチェックをOFFにするのが出来るようになります。

http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-excluding-uris

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'stripe/*',
    ];
}
```

Comment: csrf_tokenが設定されていないことによるエラーでした。

教えていただいた解決法でうまくPOST通信成功しました。ありがとうございます。